# value of $k$ for which $\sum \sin(n^{-k})$ converges

Tags: calculus

> For what value of $k$ for which the series $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{n^k}\bigg)$ converges

What i try:

We know that $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$

So $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{n^k}\bigg)<\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^k}$$

Using $p$ series test , Right side series is converge for $k>1$ and Diverge for $k\leq 1$

Is my reasoning is correct. If not then How do i solve it, Thanks

Comment: limit comparison?

Comment: I did not understand can you please explain me. Thanks

Comment: Your reasoning is correct and shows that $\sum_n \sin(n^{-k})$ converges for $k >1$, but it doesn't give when it diverges.

Comment: For divergence use $\sin(x) \ge x/2$ for $0 \lt x \lt 1$